# Can we use Specflow on VS2013 express edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow

Hello I have Visual studio 2013 Express edition and want to use Specflow on it but unable to find and install this extension.

Can someone help me know if Specflow is really available with Express edition and if yes then how to install it?

One of my friend has a Visual studio 2013 licensed version and he is able to install it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Express editions doesn't allow to install add-ins. I haven't tried but you can try to install it using a [workaround](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Visual-Studio-Express-Integration).

If you are using Visual Studio for your own needs, you can install [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) edition, which allows installing add-ins.